# Updating code for Activiti 5 to Activiti 7 upgrade

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I have a signal class using APS 1.x.x version ACTIVITI 5.x.x. I have to upgrade the Activiti So what are the code changes are to be implemented in the code as a part of this update? How to implement using TriggerableActivitiBehavior and using trigger() method?
Below is the code I want to make modifications in.

````
public class AsyncReqReplyServiceTask implements SignallableActivityBehavior {




protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncReqReplyServiceTask.class);

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



@Override
public void execute(ActivityExecution execution) throws Exception {
logger.info(execution.getId());
}



@Override
public void signal(ActivityExecution execution, String signalEvent, Object signalData) throws Exception {
PvmTransition transition = execution.getActivity().getOutgoingTransitions().get(0);
execution.take( transition);
} ```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In APS 2.x you will find a different name for the signal method that now is named trigger. You can find all the details about the changes introduced with APS 2.x based on Activiti 7 at the following link:

https://docs.alfresco.com/process-services/latest/upgrade/#signaling-an-execution